# List of earned badges displays wrong information

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, deleted-questions

My [list of Nice Answer badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=131713) contains an error. One answer is listed twice, and one of the associated dates is impossible.  Screenshot:

[image: badge list screenshot]

I [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65690/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-using-wolfram-mathematica/65693#65693) the Mathematica question just after midnight on Sep 26. [The question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65690/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-using-wolfram-mathematica) had only been asked an hour earlier. Even if I could have earned the badge twice for the same answer, I couldn't have earned it before the question existed.

At the moment, I have four answers with score of >10. The one that's not listed is under [I don't like to downvote newbies. Am I being too soft?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59369/i-dont-like-to-downvote-newbies-am-i-being-too-soft/59371#59371) However, it was posted in the middle of the day on Aug 2, so it can't have caused my Jun 13 badge either.

Now, I wouldn't be talking this much if I didn't have a theory. I'm 99% sure that I had another answer of score >10 a while back, on a question that got deleted. (I would appreciate a 10k user's help in confirming this; I think the OP for the question was Evan Carroll.) Here's what I think happened:

- May 28

  - Got the first badge for the "minor edits answer"
- Jun 13

  - Got the second badge for the now-deleted answer
- *Some time between Jun 13 and Aug 2*

  - The question for the now-deleted answer got deleted, taking my answer with it
  - Per [the badge rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854), my existing badge was not revoked
- Aug 2

  - The "downvoting newbies answer" reached score of 10
  - Per the badge rules, no new badge was awarded
- Sep 26

  - Got the third badge for the "Mathematica answer"
  - **The code that records badge information got confused by the deleted answer's info not being available, and for some reason captured the info for the "Mathematica answer" instead**
- Sep 27

  - Got the fourth badge for the "LMSOTFY answer"

This *may* be the same bug that was reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64442/badges-listed-are-for-the-wrong-questions), but my case involves a question deletion and a somewhat different result.

EDIT:
Based on the comment — thanks @Grace Note — the now-deleted answer might actually be the cause of the May 28 badge, with everything else shuffled around more than I originally thought.

EDIT 2:
[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56434/badge-awarding-system-error/56533#56533) may or may not answer this question. May/June questions would be affected, but I'm not sure that "it will eventually fill up reasons" explains the time travel info-dupe that's happening here.

Comment: You had an answer to [Evan's "glasnost" question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51586/stackoverflow-glasnost-or-suspensions-for-joke-questions/51593#51593 "10k only, of course") which was at 12 before deletion. It was answered on May 28th, and is probably the *real* source of your first badge. If you looked at [your Minor Edits answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/can-users-please-refrain-from-making-minor-edits-to-a-question/53448#53448), it was posted on Jun 12, which makes it ineligible for the May 28th badge, but does make it eligible for the Jun 13th badge.

Comment: @Grace: Mmm, delicious keyboard waffles. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Oh, I had this in the original revision of the comment, but the deletion was on Jun 28th.

Comment: What was that question about, I seem to remember it being thought provoking and wrongly censored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badges are much, much better now - things like this doesn't happen anymore :)

Comment: Mmm... I'll take your word for it and consider this complete. (As opposed to the status I previously assigned it, "forgotten.") Attempting to replicate/check up would be way too much work.